# Make Password Fields editable in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using forms in react when i give input type = "password",it does not showing input field as editable .I am not using redux form .In React how to make input field as password ?

```
 <input className="search-placeholder"   type="password"
 value={this.state.password}  onChange={this._changePassword}  />
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: @MattWatson - I updated the code

Comment: _changePassword should update the password state by `this.setState({ password: e.target.value });`

Comment: Also, `onChange={this._changePassword.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what issue you are having without some code, but there is no special technique required.  The input would just be rendered using:

```
// For a controlled input
<input type="password" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />

// For an uncontrolled input
<input type="password" ref={ref => this.ref = ref} />
```

I made a simple example [here](https://codepen.io/alsiola/pen/KvzLXX)

Comment: It showing password as text in input field . i didnt want show password

Comment: What do you mean? When I use the input in my link it shows up as black dots for each entered character, not as text.

Comment: @NavaneethanArun the code in your post has `type='text'`